# Wildcard search in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am taking some values from front-end. Querying them and returning the result. Currently I have,

```
async fetchStats(getStatQuery: GetStatQueryDto): Promise<any> {
        const stats = await this.statModel.find({
            title: getStatQuery.title,
            weight: getStatQuery.weight
        });
        return stats;
}
```

The `getStatQuery.title` can be `undefined` if nothing is send also the `getStateQuery.weight`. Now if undefined, I want `find` to ignore that field and filter that field as a wildcard. Is there a way apart from manual checking?

Answer (score 0):

```
async fetchStats(getStatQuery: GetStatQueryDto): Promise<any> {
    const tmp = {
        title: getStatQuery.title,
        weight: getStatQuery.weight
    };
    let query = {};
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(tmp))
        if (value !== undefined)
            query[key] = value
            
    const stats = await this.statModel.find(query);
    return stats;
}
```

If you have more fields for the query, the only thing you need to do is add key value pair in `tmp` variable. The for loop will ignore fields that have undefined value.

Comment: This is how I did but I want a more cleaner and professional method if there is any. But thanks :)